# Usar Like en Linq - ASP.NET

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

Lo que sucede es que en sql server si combino un Like con un "**%**" me trae todos los registros.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE DOCUMENTO LIKE '%'
```

me trae todos los registros  de la tabla usuarios con cualquier documento.

este es mi codigo en Asp.net mvc:

```
                ListaGrabaciones = (from grabacion in db.TblGrabacion
                where grabacion.Documento == "37819962"
                select new GrabacionesSp
                 {

                       Documento = grabacion.Documento,
                       telefono = grabacion.Telefono,
                       ruta = grabacion.Ruta,
                       agente = grabacion.Agente,
                       campania = grabacion.Campania,
                       fecha = grabacion.Fecha.Value
                  }).ToList();}
```

Requiero hacer lo mismo que estoy haciendo en sql server en el where del codigo de asp.net

Hasta donde se en linq existe el cotains pero nose si funciona con el "**%**"

Answer (score 4):

Puedes hacerlo con **`Contains`** de la siguiente manera:

**Para LIKE '%abc%':**

```
list.Where(x => x.Documento.Contains('abc'));
```

**Para LIKE 'abc%':**

```
list.Where(x => x.Documento.StartWith('abc'));
```

**Para LIKE '%abc':**

```
list.Where(x => x.Documento.EndsWith('abc'));
```

---

**UPDATE**: Tener en cuenta que tanto el `Contains`, `StartWith` y `EndsWith` en conjunción con el `Where`, deben aplicarse a un objeto del tipo **`List<>`** o en su caso que implemente **`IEmumerable`**.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que esta consulta va ligada a dos peticiones al usuario que son Documento y Telefono que no son obligatorias

Entonces requiero que si el usuario digita Documento pero no Telefono en telefono este el like "%" para que en teoria me omita este y filtre por el documento que digito y todos los telefono

llegado el caso que sea lo contrario me filtre por todos los documentos y el telefono que digito

Comment: @Jeison: De acuerdo, pero **eso no es lo que planteas en la pregunta** (sería otra pregunta). Con lo que te he indicado ya tienes la idea para continuar programando y probando hasta que te salga. Animo!

Comment: @RafaelAcosta si no estoy equivocado el Contains no se transforma en Like para sql sino que trabaja sobre la lista que ya recibio desde sql Server, por eso viendo lo que necesitaba no use ese metodo

Comment: @Jeison: Es correcto, el Contains debes aplicarlo a una Lista, o sea, después del `ToList()` en tu ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Podes utilizar [SqlMethods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Linq_SqlClient_SqlMethods_Like_System_String_System_String_) en linq.

Sería algo así:

```
ListaGrabaciones = (from grabacion in db.TblGrabacion
    where SqlMethods.Like(grabacion.Documento, "%37819962%")
    select new GrabacionesSp
    {
        Documento = grabacion.Documento,
        telefono = grabacion.Telefono,
        ruta = grabacion.Ruta,
        agente = grabacion.Agente,
        campania = grabacion.Campania,
        fecha = grabacion.Fecha.Value
    }).ToList();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quitale el where si no vas a filtrar nada.

```
ListaGrabaciones = (from grabacion in db.TblGrabacion

            select new GrabacionesSp
             {

                   Documento = grabacion.Documento,
                   telefono = grabacion.Telefono,
                   ruta = grabacion.Ruta,
                   agente = grabacion.Agente,
                   campania = grabacion.Campania,
                   fecha = grabacion.Fecha.Value
              }).ToList();}
```